# "The process cannot access the file --- because it is being used by another process" when making txt file C#

Tags: c#

```
string path = @$"c:\Users\asmet\Desktop\Database1/{username}";

if (File.Exists(path) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating new file..");
    File.Create(path);
          
    // this is where the error is
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        sw.WriteLine($"rf = {rf}");
        sw.WriteLine($"pf = {pf}");
        sw.WriteLine($"sf = {sf}");
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm super new to C# and I don't really know what I am doing, but whenever I try to make a new file to safe rf, pf, and sf which are all number values it crashes.

This is in VS Code in a console application.

Username is from `Console.ReadLine()` in earlier code

Exact error message :

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'c:\Users\asmet\Desktop\Database1\ausernameientered' because it is being used by another process.'

`DataBase1` is just a folder

I've tried looking at forms relating to the issue but after awhile of searching I never found a solution, I want the code to make a new file at the location specified and then put the values in the text document, then close it, so I can save and look at the data later for a school project.

What happened is it crashes every time after I enter in the "username" and it tries to create a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take out:

```
        File.Create(path);
```

it might work.

> StreamWriter(String, Boolean)
> Initializes a new instance of the
> StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default
> encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either
> overwritten or appended to. **If the file does not exist, this
> constructor creates a new file**.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I'll accept yours as an answer when the cooldown ends.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create opens a file stream. You should switch

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) **// this is where the error is**
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    sw.WriteLine($"rf = {rf}");
    sw.WriteLine($"pf = {pf}");
    sw.WriteLine($"sf = {sf}");
    sw.Close();
}
```

With

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = File.Create(path)) **// this is where the error is**
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    sw.WriteLine($"rf = {rf}");
    sw.WriteLine($"pf = {pf}");
    sw.WriteLine($"sf = {sf}");
    sw.Close();
}
```

You can’t have 2 file streams open at once.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to explicitly call `Close` inside a `using` block - when the block exits, the object is disposed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.WriteAllLines` to create and write lines to a file. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-7.0):

> ***Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then closes the file.***:

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating new file...");

    File.WriteAllLines(path,
        new[]
        {
            DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            $"rf = {rf}",
            $"pf = {pf}",
            $"sf = {sf}"
        });
}
```